# Connect to an Oracle DB

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, oracle

I tried to connect Oracle at SP Designer 2010. I try to do it with custom connection string.

```
    Provider Name: Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle
    My connection String: 
    First try:
    Data Source=/// User ID=/// Password=/// Integrated Security=No
    Second try:
    Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=///)(PORT=////))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=LIVE)));User Id=///;Password=///;
```

But it keeps give me the same warning and error. I searched a lot but couldn't find the reason.

> The selected authentication option saves the username and password as
> clear text in the data connection. Other authors of this Web site can
> access this information.
>
> Server Error: An error occured while retrieving the list of Databases
> from ///: The webs erver cannot connect to the specified data source
> because the query may contain errors, the data source may be
> unavailable or configured improperly, or your Web site is behind proxy
> server or firewall.
>
> If your Web site is behind a proxy server or firewall,verify that your
> server administratır has configured the Data Retrşeval Services HTTP
> proxy server setting for Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation.

What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a data source for oracle, testing and using that? That's how I would do it anyway.

Comment: Yes I wrote queries. I try to connect at SP on Server. Do I right?

Comment: Here is a good little guide for making a odbc datasource with Oracle. http://www.interfaceware.com/manual/odbc_oracle.html

Answer (score 2):

Prior to your connection reference, you need to install an Oracle Client on your development machine, and as Hugo says, test the connection elsewhere... e.g. from the control panel ODBC connection planel.
Tracy Sells has a connection tester, created in .NET - available from: http://tsells.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/oracle-connection-tester-for-net-applications/

This should kick off your testing.